# Android: Can one googleApiClient update the geofence setup by another googleApiClient in the same app

Tags: android, location, google-api-client, android-geofence

Android [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi#addGeofences%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) says that "If an existing geofence with the same request ID is already registered, the old geofence is replaced by the new one, and the new PendingIntent is used to generate intents for alerts."

Does it hold when using same googleApiClient or when there are multiple googleApiClients in the app setting up geofences

Thanks in advance.

PS: Please give reason before down voting the question, so that I can improve.